# Insert variable string into prefix of cell

Tags: ms-access

I have a text field with data ranging in length from 3 to 6. All cells need to contain a string that has a length of 6. I would like to insert "0"'s as a prefix, the number of zeros equal to the difference between the cell length and 6.

So:

```
123
1123
11123
111123
```

Would be:

```
000123
001123
011123
111123
```

Answer (score 0):

in an update query, update the field's value to format(field,"000000")